TCP out-of-order and GRO feature with linux kernel 5.14
according to the RFC9293, the PSH flag will be set in the last TCP segment created from the buffer (Ref. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9293#name-send).
I'm in a scenario where the traffic from the source VM goes to an intermediate VM before to reach the destination VM. The intermediate acts as a packets forwarder.
On the intermediate node the GRO is enabled and when the last packet (with PSH flag on) is received, it's soon pushed before the others. As consequence, the last fragment is the received before the others on the destination VM. This requires a re-ordering of the packets and an increasing of the packets processing on the destination. In turn, there is a reduction of the amount of packets per seconds processed on the application at destination. By disabling GRO the problem disappears but this is not advisable since GRO improve performances.
The RFC9293 does not indicate the behavior when GRO is enabled but this is the current behavior observed with kernel 5.14.
Is there any reason for why there is this logic in the GRO? Is it correct and, if so, why?
thanks

this may be related to your problem; I'd blame the virtualised hardware.

thanks for the feedback but it seems more related on the transmission side, while the problem I'm observing is on the receiving side.
